# Dell Inspiron 1525 is unable to boot

Tags: boot, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525.

It displays the following error on being turned on: "Internal hard disk drive not found and no bootable devices."

So what can I do now? I tried but no success.

Comment: You say you tried. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

> Unplug the system, remove the battery, and then remove and reconnect the hard drive.  If it's then still not seen, the drive has failed.

Another option

> If your hard drive is not recognized, that may indicate that it has failed. My suggestion would be to try booting to your Dell drivers and utilities disc. Insert the disc, then tap the F12 key when you boot and select the option to boot from the DVD drive. If you are not able to boot to the DVD drive, go to downloads and grab the Dell diagnostic package that can be used to create a bootable USB flash drive. Try booting to that and run the diagnostics from there.

[Source](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/disk-drives/f/3534/t/19519905)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Dell diagnostics from the bios, at startup.

How to start ePSA Diagnostics?

To run the Enhanced Pre-boot System Assessment (**ePSA**) diagnostics on a Dell desktop or all-in-one system, perform the steps below:

Restart the computer.
As the computer boots, press  when the Dell Splash Screen appears.
At the One Time Boot menu, press the  arrow key to highlight Diagnostics and press 
A graphical menu listing all discovered devices in the system is now displayed and the express diagnostics should run (Takes about 4 minutes).
To run the Enhanced Pre-boot System Assessment (ePSA) diagnostics on a Dell Portable, perform the steps below:

Shutdown the computer.
Press and Hold the  key while pressing the power button, then release both.
A graphical menu listing all discovered devices in the system is now displayed and the express diagnostics should run (Takes about 4 minutes).

Note any error codes for the hard drive and find it on the charts below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sources of Information:
[Dell Support 1](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN115162/EN)
[Dell Support 2](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN288966/EN#ePSA-Diagnostics)